# Does the total energy of a system equal the sum of the energy of its products when discussing a particle decay?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

So say I have a particle decay

$$a \rightarrow b+c$$

I am aware that by conservation of energy the initial energy and final energy should be equal.

$$E_i = E_f$$

However does that also mean that the total final energy of the system would be equal to the sum of the energy of the resulting particles?

$$E_f = E_b + E_c$$

Comment: By $E_b$ and $E_c$, do you include both, the kinetic energy and the mass energy?

Comment: Yes, I meant Eb as the total energy of particle b, and Ea as the total energy of particle A.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, energy is always conserved and is additive. The total energy before the decay is the sum of the rest energy and kinetic energy of particle a. The total energy afterwards is the sum of the rest energies and kinetic energies of b and c.

$$E_i = m_ac^2 + K.E_a$$
$$E_f=(m_b+m_c)c^2 + K.E_b + K.E_c$$

Comment: What about potential energy? In the case of EM interacting particles, potential energy might be close to zero when they are detected. But talking about quarks...?